# Connecting to PostgreSQL instance hosted in cloud foundry

Tags: postgresql, cloud-foundry

I have created an postgresql instance from market place in my space who's instance name is : stack-uaa-postgresql

I want to connect to it from console so that i can execute sql queries .

I followed this document :

> https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/ssh-services.html

and executed this command :

> cf create-service-key stack-uaa-postgresql postgresqlkey

and then validated it using :

> cf service-key stack-uaa-postgresql postgresqlkey

and I got following response :

```
 {
 "dbname": "removed",
 "hostname": "removed",
 "password": "removed",
 "port": "33784",
 "ports": {
  "5432/tcp": "33784"
 },
 "uri": "removed",
 "username": "removed"
}
```

I have removed values.

But when I am trying to do tunneling using ssh in my postgresql using below command I am getting exception :

```
> cf ssh -L 63306:<username>:<password>@<host internal ip>:33784
> stack-uaa-postgresql
```

> FAILED App stack-uaa-postgresql not found

what is it that I am missing , is there alternate way to making connection with cloud foundry postgresql

Comment: What programming language are you using to connect postgresql instance?

Comment: I am able to consume connection in Spring boot application

Comment: okay. what exactly the problem is?

Answer (score 4):

I know it’s confusing, but for tunneling you need to deploy an actual app to the space where your database is located and you are tunneling to that app via the cf command (I know it makes no sense, why you need an app there, but as far as I know there is no other way):

`cf ssh -L localhost:<localport>:<remotehost-ip:<remoteport> <app-name> -N`

Also don’t forget to call `cf enable-ssh <app-name>` (one time) for the app you will use for the tunnel.

Comment: For the host app, you could push PHPPgAdmin (https://github.com/cloudfoundry-samples/cf-ex-phppgadmin).  It would give you something into which you can `cf ssh` for your tunnel plus you'll get a web GUI that you can use to access your data.

Comment: It's all about security. Your database service has no route directly exposed to public access which is a very basic security practice. On top of that Cloud Foundry enforces strict security within the platform, allowing only the bounded applications to have network connectivity to the database.